# Add data row(s) to a tibble depending on the content of a single column

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr, tidyverse, tidyr

I want to automatically add one or more rows to an existing `tibble` depending on the values present in one of the `tibble` columns.

***Data***

```
    A   B   C   D     E
1   1   1   1   5   7.81
2   1   1   1   4   13.12
3   1   1   1   5   3.39
4   1   1   1   4   3.28
5   1   1   1   5   2.69
6   1   1   1   2   5.70
7   1   1   1   1   8.22
```

***Expected Output if '3' is missing from 'D'***

```
    A   B   C   D     E
1   1   1   1   5   7.81
2   1   1   1   4   13.12
3   1   1   1   5   3.39
4   1   1   1   4   3.28
5   1   1   1   5   2.69
6   1   1   1   2   5.70
7   1   1   1   1   8.22
8   1   1   1   3   0.00
```

In the `tibble` column `D` the values should range from `1:5` depending on the data set.

I want to be able to identify whether one or more numbers from this range are missing from column `D`, which if one value (e.g. 3) is missing I want to add a new row that copies the data in columns `A : C` and enters 3 in column `D` and `0` in column `E`. If two or more values are missing (e.g. `3` and `4`) I want to add two rows, etc.

Comment: ```Data %>% complete(nesting(A,B,C), D = seq(min(D), max(D), 1L))```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `tidyr::complete`:

```r
library(tidyverse)

Data %>% 
     complete(nesting(A,B,C), D = seq(min(D), max(D), 1L))

#> # A tibble: 8 x 5
#>       A     B     C     D     E
#>   <int> <int> <int> <int> <dbl>
#> 1     1     1     1     1  8.22
#> 2     1     1     1     2  5.7 
#> 3     1     1     1     3 NA   
#> 4     1     1     1     4 13.1 
#> 5     1     1     1     4  3.28
#> 6     1     1     1     5  7.81
#> 7     1     1     1     5  3.39
#> 8     1     1     1     5  2.69
```

I'd recommend not using `0` instead of `NA` but if you want to add them at the bottom and have them as `0` then this works:

```r
Data %>% 
     complete(nesting(A,B,C), D = seq(min(D), max(D), 1L)) %>% 
     arrange(is.na(E)) %>% 
     mutate(E = replace_na(E, 0))

#> # A tibble: 8 x 5
#>       A     B     C     D     E
#>   <int> <int> <int> <int> <dbl>
#> 1     1     1     1     1  8.22
#> 2     1     1     1     2  5.7 
#> 3     1     1     1     4 13.1 
#> 4     1     1     1     4  3.28
#> 5     1     1     1     5  7.81
#> 6     1     1     1     5  3.39
#> 7     1     1     1     5  2.69
#> 8     1     1     1     3  0
```

<sup>Created on 2019-06-20 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Comment: A perhaps slightly tangential question. Your code works great, but a little further down I had some other code that counted the number of occurences of each value in column D `times_entered = count(Data, D) %>% select(n)` but this now counts the new values. Is there a way of also setting this count to 0 as with column E? Thanks.

Comment: @Joe_Roberts ```Data %>% complete(nesting(A,B,C), D = seq(min(D), max(D), 1L)) %>% add_count(D) %>% mutate(n=(!is.na(E))*n) %>% group_by(D) %>% summarise_at(vars(n),.funs = mean) %>% pull(n)``` just a doodle. there could be better solutions.

Comment: Unfortunately it still returns a count of 1 for E columns with 0.00 `[1] 1 1 1 2 3`!

Comment: @Joe_Roberts well seems you decided to go with `0` instead of `NA` then: ```Data %>% complete(nesting(A,B,C), D = seq(min(D), max(D), 1L)) %>%  arrange(is.na(E)) %>% mutate(E = replace_na(E, 0)) %>% add_count(D) %>% mutate(n=(E!=0)*n) %>% group_by(D) %>% summarise_at(vars(n),.funs = mean) %>% pull(n)```

Comment: Yes, sorry I should have mentioned that in my previous reply! The new code works, thank you very much! As an aside, can I ask why you don't recommend using `0` instead of `NA`?

Comment: @Joe_Roberts `NA` means missing data while `0` is number (generally speaking) which means data has been recorded and came out as 0. That's why measurement tools use bogus numbers like -9999 for missing data rather than just putting 0.